# How to use same object between diffrent methods

Tags: java, oop

I am novice to Java coding.

I wanted to know how to pass the same object between different methods?

```
 Ex:
 Class A
 {
  //Declaring an object say
  Object obj;

  public void Method1()
  {
    //Here i want to use some method of obj
    obj=new Object();
    obj.Metod1();
  }

  public void Method2()
  {
    //Here i want to use another method of obj
    obj.Metod2();
  }
}
class B
{
 A aObj=new A();
 aObj.Method1();
 aObj.Method2();
}
```

From the above code, how can i use the object created in Method1() can be used in Method2?

This is my actual code:

```
public class UtilityFunctions 
{
    File fileName;
    public static FileWriter fwObj;
    public static BufferedWriter bwObj;
    Logger App_log;

    UtilityFunctions()
    {
        fileName=new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\TempFile.html");
        Logger App_log=Logger.getLogger(UtilityFunctions.class);
        try
        {
            if(!fileName.exists())
                fileName.createNewFile();
            this.fwObj=new FileWriter(fileName);
            this.bwObj=new BufferedWriter(fwObj);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeHeader()
    {
        try
        {
            this.bwObj.append("<html><body><table border='1' style='widht:300px'><tbody><tr><th>Date</th><th>Position</th><th>Site</th></tr>");
            this.bwObj.flush();
//          this.bwObj.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeFooter()
    {
        try
        {
            this.bwObj.append("</html></body></table></tbody>");
            this.bwObj.flush();
            bwObj.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void writeReport(String strstrPositionName)
    {
        DateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date date=new Date();
        String strCurrentDate=format.format(date);

        try
        {

            String strFormattedString="<tr><td>"+strCurrentDate+"</td><td>"+strstrPositionName+"</td><td>SomeSite</td></tr>";
            App_log.info("Printing the Line as: "+strFormattedString);
            this.bwObj.append(strFormattedString);
            this.bwObj.flush();
//          bwObj.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

I would like to call above methods like
Class TempClass
{
 public static void main(String args[] args)
 { 
   UtilityFunctions obj=new UtilityFunctions();
   obj.writeHeader();
   obj.writeReport("Message1");
   obj.writeReport("Message2");
   // I may add many write Report statements here.
   obj.writeFooter();
  }
}
```

The problem i see here, writeHeader is working fine, but at execution of writeReport I am getting NullPointer Exception. How to overcome this?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at UtilityFunctions.writeReport(UtilityFunctions.java:71)
    at TempClass.writeDetailedReport  etc.........
```

Comment: Lack of research. There's tons of tutorials for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can pass the object frome one method to another

```
 public void method1()
      {
        Object objToBePassed=new Object();
        method2(objToBePassed);
      }

      public void method2(Object passedObject)
      {
        // your logic
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create your objects within constructor of the class, and then you can easly use this object. for example:

```
class YourClass {
   private Object obj;
   public YourClass() { //constructor
      obj = new Object();
   }
   public void method() {
      //your logic
   }
```

To sum up, If you create fields of your class in constructor you don't worry about null pointers and all of class methods have access to those objects. If you want to use private field outside your class, for example in method from other class you should use getter method and pass object in argument:

```
public void otherMethod(Object obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare your object as a field for your class:

```
class MyClass
{
    private Object obj;

    //...Rest of class goes here
}
```

Initialize the object in your constructor so that it is not null when you want to access it.

```
public MyClass()
{
    this.obj = new Object();
}
```

Now you can access it from your two methods as you wish.

```
public method1()
{
    this.obj.doSomething();
}
public method2()
{
    this.obj.doSomethingElse();
}
```

All in all, it can look something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private Object obj;

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.obj = new Object();
    }

    public method1()
    {
        this.obj.doSomething();
    }

    public method2()
    {
        this.obj.doSomethingElse();
    }

}
```

Now if you want to actually pass an object from one method to another but don't want it to be accessible to any other methods, you can make it a parameter like this:

```
public method1(Object obj)
{
    obj.doSomething()
}
```

And then you can call the method from somewhere else passing specific instances of the object type.

```
public method2()
{
    Object obj1 = new Object();
    Object obj2 = new Object();

    this.method1(obj1); //All actions in method1 will be done to obj1
    this.method1(obj2); //All actions in method1 will be done to obj2
}
```

Passing parameters is especially useful if you want to call a single method several times, but have it act on different inputs.

Comment: Though i did the same thing, but still getting NullPointerException.

Comment: What is NewSampClass? Clearly the stack trace you're giving does not correspond to the code you claim to be using.

Comment: Also don't cut off the trace. Please show the whole thing.